# Tkinter GUI in RPi for arduino project with multiple sensor input

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I have an *arduino* robot collecting 5 different sensor data (flame, gas, distance, temperature and metal sensors). Now  I don't have any problems displaying these in the serial monitor of my *arduino* *IDE*. But I'm having trouble when I connect the *arduino* to the *RPi* and try to display them separately via a *TKinter* *GUI*, they are all displayed together and I can't find a way to separate the data and insert them to separate logs on the display.

So far I've tried:

1. Software Serial - dropped because of the lack of documentation so I couldn't go further to setting it up on the *RPi* side.
2. split() - this causes so much headaches as the serial data is continous with a few seconds gap and I keep getting index errors.

The arduino side of things:

```
#define trigPin 12
#define echoPin 13
#include<dht.h>
dht DHT;
#define DHT11_PIN 3

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  Serial1.begin (9600);

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() 
{ 
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;

  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println(" ");
  Serial.print (DHT.temperature, 1);
  Serial.println(" ");
  delay(5000);
}
```

The python side of things:

```
    from tkinter import *
import serial
import time
ardSerialData = serial.Serial("COM5", 9600)
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("sensor data")
root.config(bg = "#828481")

rightFrame = Frame(root, width=200, height = 600, highlightthickness=2, highlightbackground="#111")
rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=100, pady=2, sticky=N+S)

UltraLog = Text(rightFrame, width = 20, height = 10, takefocus=0, highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="#333")
UltraLog.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

TempLog = Text(rightFrame, width = 20, height = 15, takefocus=0, highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="#333")
TempLog.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)

def getRaw():
    if (ardSerialData.inWaiting() > 0):
        raw = ardSerialData.readline()
        sensor = raw.split()
        return sensor

def ultDisp():
    ultData = sensor[0]
    if (ardSerialData.inWaiting() > 0):
        UltraLog.insert(0.0,ultData)
        root.after(1000, ultDisp)
    else:
        UltraLog.insert (0.0, "no Ultra")
        root.after(2000, ultDisp)

def tempDisp():
    tempData = sensor[1]
    if (ardSerialData.inWaiting() > 0):
        TempLog.insert(0.0,tempData)
        root.after(1000, tempDisp)
    else:
        TempLog.insert (0.0, "no temp ")
        root.after(2000, tempDisp)

root.after(6000, ultDisp)
root.after(6000, tempDisp)
root.mainloop()
```

These are the last attempts at my code before I gave up and came here. 
I need to help splitting up my data from *arduino* serial and displaying the sensor data in their respective logs. I've tried splitting with **space**, **#** and even **key words** before printing out data from *arduino* like *"u"* before ultrasonic sensor data and *"t"* before temperature sensor data.

Also if there is a different and easier approach to this please advice.

Comment: What does is the value of `raw = ardSerialData.readline()` after it is called?

Comment: I'd also try having a single function that reads from the serial port, splits it up and then another function (or two) to periodically update the GUI

Comment: BTW: you could send all data in one line and receive with one function. `after` may execute functions in different order and you receive distance as temperature.

Comment: @scotty3785 _raw_ is supposed to hold all the data coming in from the serial port. And then I've used sensor to hold the raw.split() values in hopes to get the specific sensor value.

Comment: @furas  I'll give that a try and get back to you! thanks for the tip!

Comment: @scotty3785 i'll give that a try! and report back! Thanks!

Comment: @scotty3785 I've tried adding a separate function to get data and split it. Now I'm getting a **NameError: name 'sensor' is not defined** at both instances of sensor[0] and sensor[1].

Comment: The neat way to fix it is to place you application inside a class so the functions can share data. The slightly messier but commonly used approach is to declare `sensor = []` outside the functions and then inside the functions use `global sensor` to use `sensor` as a global variable so that they all have access.

Comment: @scotty3785 I'm pretty vague on the usage of classes in python. I'll look up some tutorials and give it a try! Thanks again for your continued help on this Scott!